# How to create a JSON that conforms to this Swift Struct

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swift-structs

I'm really sorry if this is a bit of a dumb question but I was wondering how I could create a JSON and JSON Decoder that works with the Swift Struct below.

Thanks!

```
struct Example: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var category: String
    var year: String
    var imageName: String
    var bannerName: String
    var URLScheme: String
    var isFavorite: Bool
    
    
    struct ProductRow: Codable, Hashable {
        let title: String
        let value: String
    }
    
    let rows: [ProductRow]
    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with `JSON Decoder`? A decoder would decode `JSON` to an object. But it seems you want to go the other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with some simple instructions.

- create an instance of your model:

  ```
  let example = Example(id: 1, title: "title", category: "category", 
      year: "now", imageName: "image", bannerName: "banner", URLScheme: "https", 
      isFavorite: true, rows: [.init(title: "title1", value: "1"),.init(title: "title2", value: "2")])
  ```
- Then "encode" it with a `JSONEncoder`, convert everything to a `String` and print it:

  ```
  let json = try JSONEncoder().encode(example)
  print(String(data: json, encoding: .utf8)!)
  ```

Output:

```
{
    "category": "category",
    "id": 1,
    "URLScheme": "https",
    "title": "title",
    "isFavorite": true,
    "rows": [
        {
            "title": "title1",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "title": "title2",
            "value": "2"
        }
    ],
    "year": "now",
    "bannerName": "banner",
    "imageName": "image"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! As a learning developer, I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 different models here, you'd need to decode them separately, but generally all you'd need to do is:

```swift
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.decode([ProductRow.self], from: data)
```

See more info [here](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/json-parsing-decoding/)

Example Object:
You should probably make year an `Int`

```json
{
   "id": 1,
   "title" : "title here"
   "category": "category here"
   "year": "2022"
   "imageName": "imageName here"
   "bannerName" : "banner name here"
   "URLScheme" : "url scheme here"
   "isFavorite": false
}
```

Rows

```json
{
   "rows" : {[
      {
         "title": "the title here",
         "value": "the value here",
      },
      {
         "title": "the title here",
         "value": "the value here",
      },
      {
         "title": "the title here",
         "value": "the value here",
      }
   ]}
}
```

Comment: the `rows` JSON is not correct, you should also have a `value` field, eg, `"value": "some value"` and most likely an array of `rows` for the `let rows: [ProductRow]`.